# Google Translate English to Chinese roman letters

Tags: translation, simplified-characters, romanization

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VVIuzbpWEs) guy says every Chinese character has a pronunciation that can be written in roman letters.

Is it possible to configure [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com.br/#en/zh-CN/hi) so that when I type `hi` it translates to `Ni hao`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that does not seem to be possible. However, if you take a look at below the translation, it'll tell you the pinyin pronunciation: 
[image]